# Why am I getting buffer overflow?

Tags: c

In the below code I am getting AddressSanitizer : Heap-Buffer-Overflow. I am trying to generate Pascal`s triangle.
When i run this code in visual studio 2022 , the code runs perfectly without producing errors.

```
 int** generate(int numRows, int* returnSize, int** returnColumnSizes){
    int** ptr = (int**)malloc(numRows*sizeof(int*));
    *returnColumnSizes = (int*)malloc(numRows*sizeof(int)); 
    *returnSize = numRows; 
    for (int r = 0; r < numRows; r++) {
        ptr[r] = (int*)malloc(r+1*sizeof(int));
        returnColumnSizes[0][r] = r+1;
    }
    if (numRows == 1) {
        ptr[0][0] = 1;
    }
    else {
        ptr[0][0] = 1;
        ptr[1][0] = 1;
        ptr[1][1] = 1;
        for (int r = 2; r < numRows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < r + 1; c++) {
                if (c == 0) {
                    ptr[r][c] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    ptr[r][c] = ptr[r - 1][c - 1] + ptr[r - 1][c];
                }
            }
            ptr[r][r] = 1;
        }
    }
    return ptr;

  
}
```

Comment: From a quick glance: `c < r + 1` suggests `c` can go out of bounds. In general: it's your code, learn how to debug it.

Comment: `r+1*sizeof(int)`: did you mean `(r+1)*sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Not the error, but `returnColumnSizes[0][r] = r+1;` looks odd. If that is a pointer to a 1D array (which it appears to be), then `(*returnColumnSizes)[r] = r+1;` is probably clearer. (Though they are effectively the same.)

Comment: This isn't a [mcve].  [Edit] your question if you need debugging help.

Comment: `*returnSize`  just returns the value of one of the input parameters. Eliminate it if it is not used.

Comment: Accessing an array out of bounds is always a bug but can appear to work perfectly, that's the joy of undefined behavior. AddressSanitizer should be telling you where the overflow happens. Examine that line for errors and consider running the code in a debugger so you can examine the state while it rums and see when the problem occurs.

Comment: Muhammed Elmaghraby, `ptr[r] = (int*)malloc(r+1*sizeof(int)); returnColumnSizes[0][r] = r+1;` are certainly amiss.

Answer (score 1):

Buffer overflow simply means you are trying to access memory in the heap that you have not allocated yet. So you should check memory allocation in your code to ensure you allocate enough memory.
The starting point would be to check if the following line

```
ptr[r] = (int*)malloc(r+1*sizeof(int));
```

does allocate enough memory for you to run the loop

```
else {
        ptr[0][0] = 1;
        ptr[1][0] = 1;
        ptr[1][1] = 1;
        for (int r = 2; r < numRows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < r + 1; c++) {
                if (c == 0) {
                    ptr[r][c] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    ptr[r][c] = ptr[r - 1][c - 1] + ptr[r - 1][c];
                }
            }
            ptr[r][r] = 1;
        }
    }
```

You should assign enough memory for the number of rows with each run of the

```
ptr[r] = (int*)malloc(r+1*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: `r+1*sizeof(int)`? not `(r+1)*sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @Persixty Yeah, as I stated, that is the line with the problem. Due to operator associativity, the 1 will have no effect on the memory allocated.